# How to deal with redirects and html file references? 404 file not found

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

So I have a website setup on windows server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 deployed to a virtual directory we will call "virtdir".

Browsing to `http://localhost/virtdir/default.aspx` works fine...

I have a domain name setup that redirects to the virtdir.

So `http://example.com` essentially displays same thing I see above at `http://localhost/virtdir/default.aspx`

When browsing straight to `http://example.com` and looking at it through chromes web developer tools It displays several `404` errors telling me it cant find `.js and .css` files referenced.

However, if I browse to `http://example.com/virtdir/default.aspx` no errors and the files load fine.

Here is the existing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Libraries/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript/timezone.js"></script>
```

If I change the code to be prefixed with the folder below using ".."

```
 <script type="../text/javascript" src="Libraries/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
 <script type="../text/javascript" src="jscript/timezone.js"></script>
```

It basically breaks the other way, meaning it will now work browsing straight to `http://example.com`, but doesn't work browsing to `http://example.com/virtdir/default.aspx`

How do I get it to work both ways, without hardcoding the entire url `http://example.com/virtdir/jscript/timezone.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to hard code the entire URL, or you need to add virtual directories to your Libraries and jscript folders so that the same path exists in both sites.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adding virtual directories to other folders so they exist on *both* sites? It is the *same* site. It is just being accessed in different ways. It has a URL redirect from http://example.com/virtdir to http://example.com/ to make the URL clean for end user... Is it possible that I need more advanced redirect expressions to "deal" with different scenarios?

Comment: Ok so if the user is being redirected from /virtdir to / then the path to your js files should work right off of the root. You should also put a leading slash on your src attributes like so: src="/Libraries/dojo/dojo/dojo.js", so that they are all relative to the root.